# Spring bean validation for empty request body

Tags: java, spring, validation, bean-validation, spring-rest

I have a model class with bean validation constraints (eg. @NotNull, @NotEmpty, ...) for some properties. Everything works fine in terms of validating individual properties, however, when the whole request body is empty, the error will contain only the first missing property (the first property with @NotNull or @NotEmpty annotation), I need to return a better error message when the whole request is empty, so instead of spring returning "some field (the first missing property in the class) cannot be null", I want to return: " The request body cannot be empty".

Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Bean validation check done by spring before entering inside controller so you have no control over error messages. If you want to give your own error message then validate the requestbody by itself and throw exception accordingly.

Comment: In your controller try to add @NotNull(message = your Message) to the requestbody Parameter.